# How to Display UIDatePicker Dates in Hindi with English Numbers/Digits

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, uidatepicker, nslocale

I want to display date in date pickers in Hindi language but the digits in English.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4kSs.png)

I was able to get the screenshot by setting the language of the device to Hindi and digits to English.
But I want to achieve it programatically.

I tried:

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker;
[datePicker setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@“hi”]]; 
//or @“hi_IN”
```

but what I get is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmhoE.png)

So, how can I set the digits to be in English?